# Are there any known text analysis NLP bots that read 8k filings, news, twits, articles - "understand" them and trade based on their derived meaning?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, news, nlp

I want to build an NLP bot that "reads" and understands meaning and sentiment of articles, twits and trades on them. E.g. understand general sentiment of comments under important financial blog posts and derives potential direction to trade.

what lib or data source should I use first to build a scalper bot that does it? Reddit, twitter, citron research, "financial times"?

Comment: Was at a conference a couple weeks back where one of the talks was about precisely this.  It's definitely possible (to implement, quality of trading aside).  I'd be very surprised if you could get anything particularly quality off the shelf for free.

Comment: @Chris, what conference ? name? pls

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/company/events/conferences/matlab-computational-finance-conference-nyc/2019.html

Comment: I wonder if you have any updates for this